# Migration from APK to bundle with new certificats

Tags: google-play, migration, apk, bundle, store

I changed sign APK key to new one.

I have done all from menu "Use a new app signing key (this requires ongoing dual releases)"

I uploaded proof-of-rotation.

What should I do next?

I'm trying upload old APK with old key,
but then I trying uploading bundle, I'm getting:

```
Unable to sign APKs with min SDK 21 without the legacy key. Ensure that your App Bundle is having minSdk version greater than or equal to 28.
```

Should I upload two app: one apk with old keys, and bundle with new key and minsdk 28?

Why "Unable to sign APKs with min SDK 21 without the legacy key" I provided it then created proof-of-rotation file.

Comment: your min sdk is 21 and it requires 28 because google changes its policy for play console.

Comment: do I need to upload two versons: old apk, and new bundle with new keys and minsdk 28?

Comment: i don,t think the mismatch is minsdk version and most of the android will support sdk 28

Comment: ok, but how to sign bundle with the legacy key?

Comment: When you are going to make it will automatically generate signed certificate in android studio

Comment: but this bundle will be the same app as old? but google play will create as a new app?

Comment: Yeah its same but its only sdk upgrading